# Is there a convenient way to manage hosted MongoDB instances linked to an heroku app?

Tags: mongodb, plugins, heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

Most of my heroku apps use one of the addons providing hosted MongoDB (i.e. [MongoLab](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab) or [MongoHQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq)). A common task for me is to dump the remote data and load it into a local instance for development/debugging. Another task is to open a console logged in to a remote instance.

Is there a convenient way to derive the connection parameters to the remote instances and perform common tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a [CLI plugin for working with MongoDB storage](https://github.com/Empeeric/heroku-mongo):

Install it by running:

`$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/Empeeric/heroku-mongo.git`

Then you can get a db-dump of the current data:

`$ heroku mongo:dump`

and later restore that data.

`$ heroku mongo:restore`

(One caveat is the copy of `system.*` collections. Watch out for these)

You can also simply `heroku mongo` to open a console to the current DB associated with you app (specified by `MONGOLAB_URI` or `MONGOHQ_URL`)

Hit `heroku mongo --help` for the other commands.

**Edit:**

I'm added two aliases for the `dump` and `restore` commands.
Also added a flag to automaticly load dumped data into a local DB:

`$ heroku dump -l`

this will dump the DB used by the app (inferred from `heroku config`) and load it to a local instance into a DB named the same as the app.